# oh my zsh binaries

Tags: command-line, zsh

I am trying to set a few permanent aliases in my terminal

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/orca 
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' 
alias chem='wine "c:/chemcraft/chemcraft.exe" '
```

but I have to enter each one of these separately each time I reopen the terminal.
*oh my zsh* seems not to care at all about my `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*zsh* does not read `.bash_profile` (the name indicates that it belongs to *bash*) because it has its own configuration files.

Generally, you can put aliases for *zsh* in `~/.zshrc`. If you are using *oh my zsh* you can also create a file with extension `.zsh` in `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` for example `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh`